# Adding Adsense on a CCK field

Tags: entities, javascript

First of all I'm using drupal 6.19.
I'm trying to add adsense on my site unsuccessfully. =/
I want to put my adsense on a CCK field but isn't working.
When I put the code on a block everything works fine. But in a CCK field I'm in trouble.
Both, block and CCK field, are set to input format FULL HTML.
I don't know why doesn't work in the CCK field. Can anyone help me?

Comment: quickly, regardless of the definition of "FULL" HTML, it strips out javascript as well as most CSS class= and other constructs.  So, if what you are trying has these, you need to send them out verbatim by creating another filter that does absolutely nothing.  obviously (I hope) this does open some security issues...

Comment: Any particular reason not to simply use [AdSense module](http://drupal.org/project/adsense)?

Answer (score -1):

Try stripping the line breaks. Like they should be all going in one line.